# AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to do a grid search, but I am having an error code:`AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'add'` that I cannot resolve. Any idea?

Here's my import:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM,Dropout
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

Then I create my function create_model:

```
#Create the model
def create_model(neurons=1):
    # create model
    # add 1st layer with 50 nodes/perceptons, each will process (2,6) matrix block
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(2, 6), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(6))
    #Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

After creating my function I call KerasClassifier:

```
X_train=train
y_train=label
# create model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
# define the grid search parameters
neurons = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
param_grid = dict(neurons=neurons)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: I think I understood why I have this error, I forgot to put `model=Sequential()` in my function `create_model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You forgot to add `model=Sequential()` right at the top your of `create_model():`